# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, django, web

I wrote this code and now i'm stuck with this error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')

this is script file
displayCart(cart);
function displayCart(cart) {    //cart is perameter actually

```
    var cartString = "";
    cartString +=  "<h5>This is your cart</h5>";

    var cartIndex = 1;
    for (var x in cart){
        cartString += cartIndex;
        console.log(document.getElementById("nam" + x).innerHTML +" | " + "Qty:" + cart[x] );
        cartString += document.getElementById("nam" + x).innerHTML +" | " + "Qty:" + cart[x] + "</br>" ;
        
        cartIndex +=1;

    }
            
}
```

thank you

Comment: Seems the DOM element `"nam" + x`, doesn't exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, the error happened while trying to execute this part of the code

`document.getElementById("nam" + x).innerHTML`, which means the element with id `"nam" + x` does not exist.

I cannot help further as i don't know what `cart` is or without looking at your html.

Consider logging `"nam" + x` and check if an element with that ID exists in the html where you're running the script